# Search for specific value in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need some help,

Here an example array that reflect real-life case:

```
$a = array (
    array('fruit' => 'banana', 'color' => 'yellow'),
    array('fruit' => 'apple', 'color' => 'red'),
    array('fruit' => 'melon', 'color' => 'green')
);

$key = array_search('apple', $a, true);
echo $a[$key]['color'];
```

I already tried to retrieve key using array_search in hope i could get the key but it cannot works, so how should i code when i want to retrieve color of apple?

PS: I tried to avoid looping, due to performance in large data

Answer (score 3):

```
// loop throgh array
    foreach ($a as $item){
       if ($item['fruit'] === 'apple'){
         echo $item['color'];
       }
    }
```

Comment: any possibilities without loop (that i avoided)

Comment: Apologies for the spelling error, first line should say "loop through array"

Answer (score 1):

try to change your table like this:

```
<?php
$a = array ( 
    'banana' => array('color' => 'yellow'),
    'apple' => array('color' => 'red'),
    'melon' => array('color' => 'green'),
);

echo $a['banana']['color'];

?>
```

Should be simple :)

Comment: it's not possible currently, data above only example for real-life usage

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to use the loop from PiX06 example :(

Answer (score 1):

Check this out -

```
foreach ($a as &$arr){
if (array_search('apple',$arr)!==false){
  echo $arr['color'];
 }
}
```